# Making a User A Company Administrator fails with error - Azure Ad Graph

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a method that Creates a user using Azure Graph API (User gets created successfully) and then tries to add the user to Company Administrator Group, but I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The context is already tracking the entity.

Result StackTrace:  
at System.Data.Services.Client.EntityTracker.AddEntityDescriptor(EntityDescriptor descriptor)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.AddObject(String entitySetName, Object entity)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.DirectoryObjectCollection.AddDirectoryObjectAsync(IDirectoryObject item, Boolean deferredSave)
```

I get the error when I hit this line:

```
await drrole.Members.AddDirectoryObjectAsync(usr as GraphClient.DirectoryObject);
```

Here is the complete body of the function:

```
await client.Users.AddUserAsync(graphUser);

var directoryRoles = await client.DirectoryRoles.ExecuteAsync();
var companyAdminRole = directoryRoles.CurrentPage.FirstOrDefault(m => m.DisplayName == "Company Administrator");
if (companyAdminRole != null)
{
    var drrole = client.DirectoryRoles.GetByObjectId(companyAdminRole.ObjectId);
    var usr = await client.Users.GetByObjectId(graphUser.ObjectId).ExecuteAsync();
    await drrole.Members.AddDirectoryObjectAsync(usr as GraphClient.DirectoryObject);
}
```

I'm using the 2.1.0 version of the SDK:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the code below:

```
 var directoryRoles = activeDirectoryClient.DirectoryRoles.ExecuteAsync();
        var companyAdminRole = directoryRoles.Result.CurrentPage.FirstOrDefault(m => m.DisplayName == "Company Administrator") as DirectoryRole;
        if (companyAdminRole != null)
        {
            var drrole = activeDirectoryClient.DirectoryRoles.GetByObjectId(companyAdminRole.ObjectId);
            var usr = activeDirectoryClient.Users.GetByObjectId(newUser.ObjectId).ExecuteAsync();
            ((DirectoryRole)companyAdminRole).Members.Add(usr.Result as DirectoryObject);
            companyAdminRole.UpdateAsync();
        }
```

As mentioned in [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2014/12/11/announcing-azure-ad-graph-api-client-library-2-0/), you can add a user to a DirectoryRole object by using the same structure of adding a user to a Group.
[image]

I have wrote a sample and tested without encountering your issue:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is no Method like this: companyAdminRole.Members.Add ... I only see drrole.Members.AddDirectoryObjectAsync

Comment: @Aram directoryRoles.CurrentPage.FirstOrDefault(m => m.DisplayName == "Company Administrator") returns an IDirectoryRole object which has the method AddDirectoryObjectAsync(), you can convert it to DirectoryRole object(as DirectoryRole I used in my code) and you'll see the .Members.Add() method. Currently there's no official MSDN/Technet articles for Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient SDK, it's quite difficult to know how/when we should use AddDirectoryObjectAsync(), hope these articles will be published soon.

Comment: Thanks you. Casting did the trick. wiered that the interface and the actual class don't match in public members.